# Saving a photo issue with .leftMirrored orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, avfoundation, uiimageorientation

So I am saving two photos using this function

```
let leftMirroredImage = UIImage(cgImage: myImage.cgImage!, scale: myImage.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored)

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, nil, nil, nil)
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(leftMirroredImage, nil, nil, nil) .
```

but for some reason, the `leftMirroredImage` is getting cut off when I view it in the Photos app. like so [image] .

here is the normal image that was saved [image]

I also noticed that the photo will get cut off like that with `.upMirrored , .downMirrored, and .rightMirrored`. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CIFilter "CIAffineTransform" and multiply your image x scale by -1 to flip your image horizontally:

```
let image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!
let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
if let ciimage = CIImage(image: image),
    let flipped = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTransform", withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey: ciimage, kCIInputTransformKey: NSValue(cgAffineTransform: transform)])?.outputImage {
    let image = UIImage(ciImage: flipped)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, image.scale)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size))
    let flippedUIImage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```